# What does it mean that statement S immediately contains statement U?

Tags: java

From [Java Language Specification, Chapter 14, Blocks and Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html):

> The sequence of execution of a program is controlled by statements, which are
>   executed for their effect and do not have values.
>
> Some statements contain other statements as part of their structure; such other
>   statements are substatements of the statement. We say that statement S immediately
>   contains statement U if there is no statement T different from S and U such that
>   S contains T and T contains U. In the same manner, some statements contain
>   expressions as part of their structure.

What does it mean that statement S immediately contains statement U if there is no statement T different from S and U such that S contains T and T contains U.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Some statements contain other statements as part of their structure; such other
>   statements are substatements of the statement.

[JLS #14.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.5) defines a statement as:

> Statement:
>
> - StatementWithoutTrailingSubstatement
> - LabeledStatement
> - IfThenStatement
> - IfThenElseStatement
> - WhileStatement
> - ForStatement

So the only statements that can have substatement (= can contain other statements) are labels, if, else, while and for.

The meaning then becomes clearer - if for example, S, T and U are defined as:

```
if(a == b) //S
    if(c == d) //T
        doSomething(); //U
```

Statement S immediately contains statement T which immediately contains statement U. But S does not immediately contain U.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following compound statement be S:

```
(a+b)+c
```

Let U be the statement `(a+b)` inside S. Then S immediately contains statement U. This is because there is no non-trivial statement T in S such that T contains U.

However, if we have something like

```
S: (a+(b+c))+d
```

Then we can let T be `(a+(b+c))`.

Comment: (a+b) is an expression, not a statement

Comment: @Code-Guru: Yes you are correct, I meant to illustrate it in more abstract terms.

Comment: @tskuzzy can you please explain a little bit more in depth?

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
if (...) { // A
  doSomething();  // B

  if (...) {  // C
    doSomethingElse(); // D
  }
}
```

The lines labeled with letters are statements. Statement A contains statements B, C, and D and only **immediately** contains B and C. Statement C immediately contains Statement D.

Comment: Technically, I don't think blocks are statements are substatement (Blocks are defined as `StatementWithoutTrailingSubstatement`), i.e. C is not a substatement of A. Admittedly, it does not really matter which is which...

Comment: @assylias C is supposed to refer to the if statement. Adding the {} for blocks might confuse the issue here a little. p.s. I think I understand your comment, but it doesn't exactly read smoothly. Is that an editing error?

Comment: My comment reads like I need some sleep ;-) The main point was that blocks technically can't have substatements and I don't think your example applies in the context of this specific question. The secondary point was: I don't think it is that important. As far as I can tell, the notion of "immediately contains" is used [only once in the whole JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4.1)...

Comment: @assylias Your answer is certainly much clearer than mine ;-)